# Mac OpenGL window movement required to show something

Tags: c, opengl, cmake, glfw

I'm starting OpenGL with C, so I started up a CLion project and got started.  For reference, I'm on a Mac 10.14.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(GLMC C)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /usr/local/lib/cmake/glfw3)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
find_package (OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package (glfw3 REQUIRED)

include_directories(/usr/local/include glad)
include_directories(${GLFW_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_library(COCOA_LIBRARY Cocoa REQUIRED)
find_library(IOKIT_LIBRARY IOKit REQUIRED)
find_library(COREVID_LIBRARY CoreVideo REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

add_executable(GLMC main.c glad.c)
target_link_libraries (GLMC
        ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
        ${COCOA_LIBRARY}
        ${COREVID_LIBRARY}
        ${IOKIT_LIBRARY}
        ${GLFW3_LIBRARY} glfw)
```

And this is my `main.c`:

```
#include "glad.h"
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "linmath.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static const struct
{
    float x, y;
    float r, g, b;
} vertices[3] =
        {
                { -0.6f, -0.4f, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f },
                {  0.6f, -0.4f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f },
                {   0.f,  0.6f, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f }
        };
static const char* vertex_shader_text =
        "uniform mat4 MVP;\n"
        "attribute vec3 vCol;\n"
        "attribute vec2 vPos;\n"
        "varying vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(vPos, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "    color = vCol;\n"
        "}\n";
static const char* fragment_shader_text =
        "varying vec3 color;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";
static void error_callback(int error, const char* description)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", description);
}
static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
{
    if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GLFW_TRUE);
}
int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;
    GLuint vertex_buffer, vertex_shader, fragment_shader, program;
    GLint mvp_location, vpos_location, vcol_location;
    glfwSetErrorCallback(error_callback);
    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 0);
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc) glfwGetProcAddress);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);
    // NOTE: OpenGL error checks have been omitted for brevity
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertex_shader, 1, &vertex_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertex_shader);
    fragment_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragment_shader, 1, &fragment_shader_text, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragment_shader);
    program = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(program, vertex_shader);
    glAttachShader(program, fragment_shader);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    mvp_location = glGetUniformLocation(program, "MVP");
    vpos_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPos");
    vcol_location = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vCol");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vpos_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vpos_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(float) * 5, (void*) 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vcol_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vcol_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(float) * 5, (void*) (sizeof(float) * 2));
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        float ratio;
        int width, height;
        mat4x4 m, p, mvp;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, &width, &height);
        ratio = width / (float) height;
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        mat4x4_identity(m);
        mat4x4_rotate_Z(m, m, (float) glfwGetTime());
        mat4x4_ortho(p, -ratio, ratio, -1.f, 1.f, 1.f, -1.f);
        mat4x4_mul(mvp, p, m);
        glUseProgram(program);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_location, 1, GL_FALSE, (const GLfloat*) mvp);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This is the sample code on their website.
I have this basic GLFW/GLAD code.  The latest versions of `glad.h`, `glad.c` and `khrplatform.h` are properly referenced.

I have installed `glfw3` through brew properly, and succesfully referenced it through C++ and XCode, but I wanted to do it in C and CLion.

The window is entirely black, until it is moved by dragging the title bar, which causes everything to work perfectly.

Comment: The program both compiles and runs, and it apparently calls at least some OpenGL functions successfully.  I see no reason at all to conclude that there is any link issue.  There could be a "my OpenGL library is broken" issue, but most likely the issue is that your OpenGL calls don't mean what you think they mean.  Even if I knew what you were expecting to see, however, I'm not enough of an OpenGL person to easily recognize what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: I'm experienced in OpenGL with other languages like Java, so this *should* be clearing the window to white.  But it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry! I figured it out. Mostly.  Basically, it was working just fine, but only *after* the window had been dragged around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is a known bug on Mac Mojave.  I fixed this by setting the window position (simulating a window drag) on the first iteration of the main loop:

```
bool hasWindowBeenFixed=false;

while(true){
    glfwSwapBuffers(); // IMPORTANT: The fix only works AFTER swap buffers has been called
    if(!hasWindowBeenFixed){
        hasWindowBeenFixed=true;
        glfwSetWindowPos(window,50,50);
    }
}
```